# Bengali Avro Keyboard not working in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I have installed Avro successfully in Lubuntu 14.04. The only problem I am facing currently is that whenever I switch to Bengali-Avro Phonetic and try to write something, I can see the suggestions in Bengali but no text is entered in the main text field. I am trying to write in these softwares: Leafpad, Libreoffice, Firefox, Chrome. Hope that I might get an answer this time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^
I followed your instruction. But still it doesn't work... Help please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the answer to my question. All I had to do is

Goto

Preferences > Language Support > Install/Remove Languages

Then, install Bangla.

Logout and Login again and Voila!!!

Avro is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

### Installation

Open Terminal and enter the following commands one by one.

1. Add `ibus-avro` repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"
   ```
2. Add key

   ```
   wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install `ibus-avro`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-trusty
   ```
5. Now you need to logout and login again or restart your computer.

### Using `ibus-avro`

1. Click the IM icon in menubar and Select Text Entry Setting
2. In *Text Entry Setting* window click + icon (marked by arrow) in left pane. Write avro in the search box (marked by arrow). Choose Bengali (Avro Phonetic) from the list and press Add button to add Avro to the list.
3. (Optional) The keyboard shortcut to switch input method has been changed to Super+Space since Ubuntu 13.10. You can change it to your preference from Text Entry Setting window.
4. Open any text editing software (like, gedit). Now Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle between English and Avro (Bengali)
5. Enjoy Avro