# Avro-Keyboard Bengali not working in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, language-support

I have installed avro-keyboard in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. I can see the avro-keyboard's icon in the status bar but when I am trying to write anything I could not see anything .

I tried the same procedure in a separate computer running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it is working fine as I could write Bengali. How can i make the Avro-keyboard to work properly in Xubuntu 14.04?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bengali Avro Keyboard not working in Lubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/483514/216503)

Comment: I tried to solve using the procedure mentioned above but could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This YouTube video tutorial will help you [Install Avro in Xubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGW3TFUuXrE)